# VBA - difference in arrays

Tags: arrays, vba

Is there a difference between the following arrays?

```
dim s() as string
redim s(1 to 2)
```

vs.

```
 dim sd() as string
 redim sd(2)
```

The reason for my question is when I store my worksheet names to the second array string variable and try printing, it gives me an error. It works when I use the first string array.

```
 sheets(sd).select 
 sheets(sd).printout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

The first sets the lower bound to 1 and the second relies on the settings for the lower bound of either 0 or 1.

Default is 0.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if the default base is used, sd(2) has 3 elements, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
redim s(1 to 2)
```

has 2 index' which is s(1) and s(2) while

```
redim sd(2)
```

has 3 index' which is s(0), s(1), and s(2).